# When playing games, windows steals focus every 10 minutes on the dot

Tags: windows-7, fullscreen, starcraft2

When playing a game in full screen mode, windows will kick me out of the game and go back to windows every 10 minutes.

I have no idea how this is happening.

1. Screen saver is not enabled
2. No scheduled tasks listed happen at that time interval

Comment: Is it just starcraft2 that does this? or is it all games?

Comment: Try closing background processes 1 by 1 until you find the one that caused it. Atleast 1 other person reported xwidget causing this behavior. http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f59/solved-games-freeze-crash-after-10-15-minutes-of-play-623058.html

Comment: @spuder How do you know it was SC2?

Comment: @chipperyman573 it's tagged "starcraft2"

Comment: All games do this.

Comment: I've tried closing everything :/

Comment: @jefferino Safe Mode?

Comment: When you say every 10 minutes, do you mean every 10 minutes starting at a random time, or at the 10 minute boundary?

Answer (score 1):

Ten minutes is often the time people set their computer to lock the screen.  So even though you may have a screen saver disabled, you still might have the timeout lock enabled.  You might also think that your movement in the game via keyboard/mouse/etc will signal to Windows to not lock but sometimes it still tries to lock.  This was the source of my problem.